# How To port OpenSSL Library in android Project

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to Port OpenSSL library in android project but i don't know the exact steps 
can any one tell me how to port OpenSSL in android project i am waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you ported openssl now or used javax.net.ssl? Would be nice to hear your solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Any One tell me How to Add OpenSSL Library in android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107721/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-add-openssl-library-in-android-project)

Comment: http://ssuman185.blogspot.sg/p/steps-for-porting-openssl-for-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to? Android provides [javax.net.ssl](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html).

If you really do want to do this, you will need to make sure OpenSSL will run with Bionic (the C library) in Android. Google is your friend - so is playing whack a mole with compile errors.